# Keyboard macro produces a series of numbers

Tags: keyboard-macros

I did some editing. Then went to `C-x C-k l` edited the stuff to suit my needs. Saved it with `C-c C-c`. Gave it a name with `C-x C-k b`. Finally, went to `~/.emacs` and did `M-x insert-kbd-macro`

To my surprise, it produced few words and a long series of numbers. I can still execute it using `M-x macroname RET` and edit it using `C-x C-k e`. So no problems.

But why those cryptic numbers in `~/.emacs`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keyboard macros record keystrokes (or keyboard *events*), which typically (although not exclusively) have a numeric representation.

Many directly represent *characters*, as characters are integers in Emacs Lisp.  e.g. The character `t` is 116:

```
ELISP> ?t
116 (#o164, #x74, ?t)
```

(Characters are therefore likely to account for all the smaller numbers.)

Larger numbers can represent more complex key events. e.g.:

```
ELISP> (listify-key-sequence (kbd "M-x"))
(134217848)
```

A few events may have non-numeric representations (e.g. `return`).

You can read all about events in the manual:

<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp) Input Events` <kbd>RET</kbd>